# How to do recursive iterators in lua?

Tags: lua, iterator

I can usually work out how to code the iterators I want in LUA.

But  recursive iterators have me beat.

For example, here's a Python recursive iterator that returns all items in a nested list:

```py
def items(x): 
  if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):
    for y in x:
      for z in items(y): yield z
  else:
    yield x

for x in items([10,20,[30,[40,50],60],[70,80]]): print(x)
```

This prints

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
```

But I can't get it going in Lua. I think it is because I don't know how to carry around the state of the recursive traversal from one step in the iteration to the next.

Suggestions?

Comment: Use a stack of "plain list" iterators. Push the iterator of the top list on the stack at the time you create your iterator. The iterator at the top of the stack is the one from which you take the next element. When in the course of iterating you come across a list, push its iterator onto the stack, and return its initial element. You need to be careful here, because the iter could be empty. When you reach the end of the iterator at the top of the stack, pop it to the next iterator, and grab the next item. This is where you need to be careful again, because the next iterator down may be empty.

Answer (score 2):

**FP style**

```
local function items(tbl, outer_iter)
   local index = 0
   local function iter()
      index = index + 1
      return tbl[index]
   end
   return
      function ()
         while iter do
            local v = iter()
            if v == nil then
               iter, outer_iter = outer_iter
            elseif type(v) == "table" then
               iter = items(v, iter)
            else
               return v
            end
         end
      end
end
```

---

**Coroutine style**

```
local function items(tbl)
   return coroutine.wrap(
      function()
         for _, v in ipairs(tbl) do
            if type(v) == "table" then
               local iter = items(v)
               local v = iter()
               while v ~= nil do
                  coroutine.yield(v)
                  v = iter()
               end
            else
               coroutine.yield(v)
            end
         end
      end
   )
end
```

---

Usage example:

```
for x in items{10,20,{30,{},{40,50},60},{70,80}} do
   print(x)
end
```

Comment: Could you clarify some things in the FP style? Namely the `while iter` condition - what var is `iter` meant to be? And what the `iter, outer_iter = outer_iter` line means? This is awesome though, I got this working with a coroutine but have wanted to try the closure route to see if it's noticeably faster.

Comment: `while iter do ... if iter()==nil then iter = outer_iter end ... end` is needed to return to the outer iterator.  This `while` loop actually executes only 1 or 2 times.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I did have to explicitly write `iter, outer_iter = outer_iter, nil` since it otherwise infinitely loops (happens when screwing around with things one doesn't understand). Nice thing is, in my use-case, it beat the coroutine version over 10000 iterations by ~4ms total, even when returning a new table, so pretty cool! Thanks, hope @Tim Menzies likes it